# Similar Triangles ratio of medians equal to ratio of angle bisectors?

Tags: geometry, triangles

If two triangles are similar, then the ratio of the lengths of their corresponding medians is equal to the ratio of the lengths of their corresponding angle bisectors.

What is confusing me with this question is isn't an angle bisector a type of median?  Since the median is technically dividing an angle wouldn't this be case?  Since I believe they are the same it would be obvious to me the ratios are the same since it would be the same lengths.

Comment: Angle bisector is not necessarily a median. The median goes from a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side. It doesn't necessarily split the angle in half. The angle bisector splits the angle in half, but doesn't necessarily go to the midpoint of the opposite side. Only in the case of an isosceles triangle and the "vertex angle" do the two concepts match up.

Comment: Isn't this the same segment though?  I am somewhat confsued by your explanation

Comment: Angle bisector exactly divides the angle in half. So the two angles it splits into are equal. The median divides the angle, but doesn't necessarily divide the angle into two equal angles. For example, given an angle of 60 degrees. The angle bisector will split this into two 30 degree angles. But the median might split it into 10 and 50.

Comment: It's not the same segment.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.geogebra.org/m/NsRjUk88 it illustrates the difference between angle bisector, altitude and median.

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be confusing but consider the angle bisector as an angle divider and a median as a side divider ,where the angle divider doesn't always divide the opposite side equally but always divides its angle equally,and a side divider will arise from an angle but won't always divide the angle equally but will surely divide the the side it reaches equally.Only in some cases is it possible that the angle divider (angle bisector) and the side divider(median) are the same or overlapping.

Comment: And the special cases are an isosceles triangle and an equilateral triangle.